# How can I prove $Y=X+Z$ is a Gaussian Random Variable iff $Z$ is a Random Variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, gauss-sums

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Gaussian Variables.
We know $Y=X+Z$.

Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent. How can I prove $Y$ is a Gaussian Random Variable iff  $Z$ is a Random Variable?

Can I use $X$, $Z$ Orthogonal and Normal thus create a Gaussian Vector hence any Linear Combination is a Gaussian Variable?

Comment: You could use characteristic functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If $X$ and $Z$ are independent random variables and $X+Z$ is a Gaussian random variable, then $X$ and $Z$ are Gaussian random variables too.

This is a result in Feller's book where it is attributed to a conjecture by P. Lévy that was proved by H. Cramér.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2150683/15941) for more details. The proof of the general statement above is not easy. But, if you know that $X$ is Gaussian (note that this is not part of the assumptions in the statement above), then, given that $Y=X+Z$ is Gaussian, there is an easy proof that $Z$ is also Gaussian via characteristic functions as suggested in ChargeShiver's comment.